# Insert FontFamily value into SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, selecteditem, font-family

The project I'm working on has ChooseFont window. I add all the FontFamily objects from "Fonts.SystemFontFamilies" to ListBox (fontFamilyList) alphabetically. I need to highlight saved font from settings (it's saved as a string).

I've the following constructor:

```
public ChooseFontWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var fonts = 
        from font in Fonts.SystemFontFamilies
        orderby font.Source
        select font;

    foreach (FontFamily f in fonts)
    {
        fontFamilyList.Items.Add(f);
    }

    fontFamilyList.SelectedItem = Properties.Settings.Default.FontFamily;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what happens? It looks like it should work. Did you use a debugger?

Comment: It do nothing. I used debugger and everything looks good. I haven't problem to highlight values from other list boxes but there I used the same variable type as in settings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible answer. I don't know if it will fix the problem without more information.

```
public ChooseFontWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var fonts = 
        from font in Fonts.SystemFontFamilies
        orderby font.Source
        select font;

    foreach (FontFamily f in fonts)
    {
        fontFamilyList.Items.Add(f);
    }

    fontFamilyList.SelectedIndex = fonts.ToList().IndexOf(Properties.Settings.Default.FontFamily);
}
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
public ChooseFontWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var fonts = 
        from font in Fonts.SystemFontFamilies
        orderby font.Source
        select font;

    foreach (FontFamily f in fonts)
    {
        fontFamilyList.Items.Add(f);
    }

    fontFamilyList.SelectedItem = fonts.FirstOrDefault(ff => ff.Name == Properties.Settings.Default.FontFamily.Name);
}
```